# GCP PubSub many-to-many (fanout) implementation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, blockchain, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using PubSub for a custom semi-centralised blockchain network where I have each node in the network publish and subscribe to transactions and blocks added to the chain.

My goal is to have a fanout approach where each node must receive the message even if one acknowledges it first. My understanding is that I will need a different subscription for each of the nodes in order to achieve the above.

When I looked into the limitations, it seems like there's a maximum number of subscriptions per project which is 10,000.

How can I achieve a the above for more than that number? Or is PubSub not a possible option for my implementation?

If not, do you recommend a specific alternative?

I'm aware of p2p methods used in other networks, but the issue there is speed of delivery which makes the network extremely slow with growth. In my case I do not care or even prefer the PubSub system to be centralised, so the "decentralised" argument here is not valid.

I thought of simply having my nodes "not acknowledging" messages, but that can be abused by anyone who touches the distributed code, and I'm not sure what other issues will arise from that.

Should I maybe have multiple projects, each with similar configs, and randomly select some of the nodes that will be listening to one and publishing to another to "relay" messages?

Any feedback, guidance, direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your limit is the number of subscription per project, I agree, create several projects. However, you can have a topic in one project and be reachable from another one. Similarly, you can have a subscription in a project and the topic in another project. There is no relay to create for that. However, pulling subscription is optimized, but it's still HTTP network traffic and if you have large volume of data, you will have similar network issues. Not sure that this design resolve that issue..

Comment: On one hand the number of subscriptions seems to be a soft-limit based on documentation, but on the other hand I'm thinking about the network quotas as well. I'm not 100% I understand clearly those limits mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#quotas (In general my message size is about 15-20KB that needs to be published to all subscriptions/nodes). Worst case I might introduce local messaging queues?

Comment: I agree with @guillaumeblaquiere's comment. And regarding the local messaging queues, this will give more durable message delivery mechanism and will probably eliminate the network issues since you will not be needing to connect over a network in sending/receiving messages.

Comment: Do all of the subscriptions need to be on the same topic? If so, you will also run up against the 10,000 subscriptions per topic limit.

Comment: Yes they all listen to the same type of data. Any node of the network can produce transaction data which all nodes need to receive to take it into account when preparing the next transaction/block and when calculating the remaining balance of an address.  I'm considering moving to AWS SQS for production as it seems their limits are much higher. Otherwise a self-hosted solution.